# Format for adding attachment to mail in gmail api

Tags: java, gmail-api

I am trying to create a draft using gmail api([link to api doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create))

I am sending the request body as follows,

```
    {
  "id": "001",
  "message": {
    "raw": "VG86IGZvb0BleGFtcGxlLmNvbQ0KU3ViamVjdDpJZ25vcmUNCg0KdGVzdCBtYWlsIGJvZHkNCg==",
    "payload": {
      "headers": [

      ],
      "mimeType": "message/rfc822"
    }
  }
}
```

Where raw contains the base64 encoded string of the following,

```
 To: foo@example.com
Subject:Ignore

test mail body
```

This is working fine, but I am struggling with adding the attachment to the mail. I tried the following, but it wont work,

```
 To: foo@example.com
Subject:Ignore

test mail body
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=##########


--##########

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

 test mail body  

 --##########

Content-Type : image/png
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sample.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64


[B@66d3c617

 --##########
```

Thanks.

Comment: There already is an answer, but still one issue: `[B@66d3c617` is a `byte[].toString()`. As that is Base64, you can do `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)`.

Comment: Thank you ,Yeah I am having trouble with encoding the attached file, means how should we encode it?  Suppose it is an image then, first convert it to byte array then convert the byte array to blob and then to base 64. Or convert the file to byte array and use it in attachment field.

Comment: Above stood "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" so I simply assumed the byte array to be Base64 ASCII text. No complicated thoughts on my side.

Comment: I am getting the attached image, but it is not being opened as it says it is corrupted in windows.I tried the following,                                                         byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(fileContent);//File contenct is byte array
             String pngData = new String(encoded,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII");
             pngData = pngData.replace("/", "_");
             pngData = pngData.replace("+", "-");
             pngData = pngData.replace("=", "*");

Comment: There are 3 different kind of [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#mime), and the padding at the end (`=`) is also configurable. `Base64.getUrlEncoder()` uses `_-` i.o. `/+`. And `getMimeEncoder` can wrap the text into lines. Is the byte data a valid png?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format for saving draft with attachment is as follows,

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"
MIME-Version: 1.0
to: receiver@gmail.com
from: sender@gmail.com
subject: Subject Text

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

The actual message text goes here

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="example.jpg"

VG86IGZvb0BleGFtcGxlLmNvbQ0KU3ViamVjdDpJZ25vcmUNCg0KdGVzdCBtYWlsIGJvZHkNCg==

--foo_bar_baz--
```

Encode the whole above code to base64 and then pass it as raw parameter in the gmail api.